# I have a heatmap generated using matplotlib and numpy, how can I use this for pose estimation?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am not looking for using any cameras for the pose estimation. How can I use the heatmap which I have created for pose estimation. The heatmap basically is a plot of the pressure value and I want to use this for some sort of pose detection in bed. Is there any way I can achieve this?[This is the image that I want to use and there will be multiple images just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c80L2.png)

Comment: There are probably some options if you collect the data and decide on the layout of the learning task. For instance, you can (1) identify the poses of interest (say there are K in total), (2) collect labeled data by recording the pressure values that are typically observed for this pose, and (3) build a classifier with K output classes to allow you to predict the probability of each pose given a new pressure value image.

Comment: Yes, so first I should go by identifying the critical points. Can you give me a baseline on how I should proceed? Can you give some resources that I should study? I am really stuck here.

Comment: Let me give a more concrete example of the steps. (1) Assume you are interested in 4 sleeping positions (back, side, fetal, and stomach).  Following your example, you have 6x6 pressure value images to connect to these poses. (2) We would need data to learn the typical pressure patterns that are connected to each of these poses. For example, you could ask a group of people to take a certain pose and record the pressure. (3) You train a classification method (e.g. multinomial logistic regression) to predict unknown poses based on pressure information only. Each pixel value is a feature.

Comment: Hey thank you! I'll ask you if I have any other doubt